# Why is a temple to Hathor in India?

Tags: india, ancient-egypt, egypt, ancient-india, temples

Many internet articles are saying that there is a temple of Deity Hathor (which is an Egyptian goddess) in Nuh district, Mewat city, Haryana state, India  .
[Exact Map's Location](https://maps.app.goo.gl/XAvuW8Qzt6gsKZV9A)

This is a reliable article regarding this-

[Embassy of Egypt In India](https://www.facebook.com/EgyptinIndia/photos/the-ruins-of-temple-of-hathor-built-during-the-third-dynasty-of-thutmose-of-egyp/2296522927028684/)

They even mention finding Papyrus Document, with Egyptian Script .

So my question is, is this true ?

If yes, do you guys have any other sources or information regarding this.

Comment: The architecture in the photos argues no. As does the top comment.

Comment: I'm not sure by what standard facebook is a reliable article. Nor do I understand why you are asking "is it true?" if you have a reliable article claiming it is true.   I can't find any citation to this being a temple of Hathor other than travel advertisements. Nothing scholarly, nothing with citations.

Comment: Architecturally the one image I keep seeing with the three repeating rounded arches bears a strong resemblance to local architecture styles, including the nearby ['tomb of Sheikh Musa combines Muslim and Rajput forms of architecture'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuh_(city)#:~:text=The%20tomb%20of%20Sheikh%20Musa%20combines%20Muslim%20and%20Rajput%20forms%20of%20architecture)

Comment: The map says this is just a 100m from the Sheik Musa tomb, on the other side of the valley. The last picture in [this blog entry](https://climber-explorer.blogspot.com/2015/05/shaking-minarets-in-nuh.html) probably shows the same ruins. It's titled "Ruins of a Haveli visible from Sheikh Musa Tomb" and with the comment "From this complex one can also see high on the hill ruins of a haveli (said to be of a local merchant).".

Answer (score 8):

Pulling together what's been said in the comments, the answer to the headline question is that **there is no such temple**.

The "reliable article" linked in the question is a Facebook post where the Egyptian Embassy in India apparently made a fanciful and fictional claim.

If the claim were true, references to this discovery should be easily found on Google Scholar. I can find no references to any Egyptian archeological finds anywhere in India or even indirect evidence of cultural contact between the two regions in ancient times.

As user ccprog has found, [a travel blog](https://climber-explorer.blogspot.com/2015/05/shaking-minarets-in-nuh.html) indicates that the ruins depicted are that of a [haveli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haveli), not a temple.